# Polymorph relationship wont let me reach to the parts table

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, inertiajs

So I have a database that has : Ad Model that polymorphs to Vehicle, Parts and Equipment model. Now I am trying to do some filtering with checkboxes, heres my front end code with Vue.js

```
import {Link, useForm} from "@inertiajs/vue3";

const props = defineProps({
    ads : Array,
    filters : Object
})


const filterForm = useForm({
    priceFrom : props.filters ? props.filters.priceFrom : null,
    priceTo : props.filters ? props.filters.priceTo :  null,
    disciplines: props.filters ? props.filters.disciplines : [],

})
const filter = () => {
    filterForm.get(route('tires'), {
        preserveState:true,
        preserveScroll: true,
    })


}
const clear = () => {
    filterForm.priceFrom = null
    filterForm.priceTo = null
    filterForm.disciplines = []
    filter()
}
```

Now filtering with prices works great because, price is in Ad model, but the disciplines are located in the Parts model, here is where I load the models

```
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request){
        $filters = $request->only([
            'priceFrom', 'priceTo', 'disciplines'
        ]);
        if(!$filters['disciplines'])
            $filters['disciplines']=[];

        $adsWithImages = Ad::with('user', 'advertisable')
            ->where('advertisable_type', 'parts')->filter($filters)->partDisciplines($filters['disciplines'])
            ->paginate(10)->withQueryString()
            ->map(function ($ad) {
                // Eager load only the necessary relationships
                if($ad->advertisable->type ==='tires'){

                $ad->load('advertisable.imageable');
                // Map the image paths
                $ad->image_path = $ad->advertisable->imageable->map(function ($imageable) {
                    return $imageable->imagePath;
                })->toArray();

                // Unset the unnecessary relation
                unset($ad->advertisable->imageable);

                return $ad;}
                return null;
            })->filter();

        return Inertia::render(
            'Home/TiresPage',
            [
                'ads' => $adsWithImages,
                'filters' => $filters,
            ]
        );
    }
```

The partDisciplines scope isnt working I have tried all of types of filtering but it always keeps going from the Model Vehicle (loops all advertisables) and throws an exception saying manufacter doesnt exist in Vehicle model (and it doesnt), how can I make my Eloquent go only into the advertisable thats of type Part, the ->where('advertisable_type', '=', 'parts'); isnt working and I dont know what else to do.
Heres the code of partDisciplines which is in Ad model
:

```
public function scopePartDisciplines($q, $disciplines){
        if($disciplines){
        foreach ($disciplines as $discipline)
        {
           return $q->where('advertisable_type', '=', 'parts')->withWhereHas('advertisable', function ($query) use($discipline){
               $query->where('manufacter', $discipline);
           });
        }}
        else
           return false;
    }
```

, one more thing I tried is to create a local scope inside of a Part model and then in the Ad model to check if the instance that called the filter scope in the Ad model is of type Part and then call the discipline method from the Part model (that didnt work either).
Now this is type of SQL I get when I do the method partDiscipline

```
SELECT
  count(*) AS aggregate
FROM
  `ads`
WHERE
  `advertisable_type` = parts
  OR (
    (
      `ads`.`advertisable_type` = vehicle
      AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          `vehicles`
        WHERE
          `ads`.`advertisable_id` = `vehicles`.`id`
          AND `manufacter` = Avon
      )
    )
    OR (
      `ads`.`advertisable_type` = parts
      AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          `parts`
        WHERE
          `ads`.`advertisable_id` = `parts`.`id`
          AND `manufacter` = Avon
      )
    )
    OR (
      `ads`.`advertisable_type` = equipment
      AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          `equipment`
        WHERE
          `ads`.`advertisable_id` = `equipment`.`id`
          AND `manufacter` = Avon
      )
    )
  )
```

How do I make my SQL only go into the Part model instead of all of them
I know this message has kinda be long, sorry for that, but this thing is hella bothering me

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
        if ($disciplines) {
            $q->where('advertisable_type', '=', 'parts')->whereHasMorph('advertisable', [Part::class], function ($query) use ($disciplines) {
                $query->whereIn('manufacter', $disciplines);
            });
        }
           return $q;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).